# Asserting precondition even after asserting precondition previously?

Tags: java

Suppose I have some code like:

```
class ObjClass{
  public int id; // for two messages that are deep copies, the id is equal, otherwise unique.
  public String message; // this can be different even if the id is equal (ie modifying a deepcopy). 
}
```

```
ObjClass instance1 = new ObjClass(123, "instance1Text");

ObjClass deepCopyofInstance1 = SomeUtil.getDeepCopy(instance1);  // looks like {123, instance1Text}

// Modify deepcopyText
deepCopyOfInstance1.message = "instance1text; //Now looks like {123, instance2Text} same id as instance1 but different message.

//Call the helper "doSomething" now

doSomething(instance1, deepCopyOfInstance1); // this will work because id of both is the same.
```

Now another helper method in the same file

```
// This method should ONLY be called if firstObj.id == secondObj.id otherwise its illegal
public void doSomething(ObjClass firstObj, ObjClass secondObj){
  Precondition.assert(firstObj.id == secondObj.id); // This is redundant for ALL valid inputs.
  // ... 
}
```

Now, here is the dilemma.

`doSomething` can technically be called with two `ObjClass` with different ids, so if the precondition is not there it will return an incorrect answer.

But all of my current use cases will have `id` equal. The issue is, not having the `precondition` leaves vunerability even if documented correctly.

What is the correct approach here? Having the precondition, makes it check the `id` again which is redundant.

Comment: Check it.  What's the harm?  It's a cheap check, and if you violate that condition in future, you'll be informed immediately by your tests.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, what if it was an expensive check?

Comment: How expensive?  If it was a huge effort, then maybe not, but very few realistic preconditions are actually expensive to check.